# Largest-area trapezoid bounded between x-axis and the quadratic function $4y = 16 - x^2$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Calculus optimization problem:

Find the dimensions of the largest possible trapezoid, by area, that fulfills the following criteria:

- longer base runs along the x-axis
- other two vertices sit above the x-axis
- bounded by the quadratic function $4y = 16 - x^2$

Comment: Any ideas?  What is the range of values that the vertices might fall in?  Can you find equations for the vertices?  The area of the a trapezoid inscribed between these curves.  And once you have a formula for area, how do you maximize it?

Answer (score 1):

For any $x \in (-4,4)$ the vertices are $(-4,0), (-x,\frac {16-x^2}{4}),(x,\frac {16-x^2}{4}),(4,0)$

$A = \frac 12 (8+2x)(\frac {16-x^2}{4})\\
\frac {dA}{dx} = ??? = 0$

Solve for $x$

Comment: Nice answer. It will be fine if you explain also that why you consider an isosceles trapezoid.

Comment: I think you are missing some devisions by 4 since the parabola is $4y=16-x^2$. It doesen't matter as it will lead to the same answer but still...

Comment: @DanielGendin thanks, fixed

Comment: @Qurultay It is given that one base is the x, axis, and the parabola is symmetric about the y axis, the parabola must be isosceles.